# theory on auto layout for iPad/iPad Retina

Tags: ios, autolayout

There is one image1 and one label1 in the view. I set auto layout in IB as 
"image1.leading equal label1.leading, multiplier=1, constant = 30"

I thought it would get different visual distance between on iPad and on iPad Retina. But actually they are same.

This is why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS uses points to abstract away from the physical pixels of the screen.

In this case, your constant is set to 30 *points* (not pixels). This is where the `scale` of a display comes into play.

The iPad has a `scale` of `1.0` and the iPad retina has a scale of `2.0`. The scale is used as a multiplier for points to translate them to pixels when rendering.

Your 30 points is shown as 30 pixels on the iPad (1.0 x 30 = 30) and 60 pixels on the iPad retina, (2.0 x 30 = 60). However, the pixels are more densely packed in the iPad retina, so the physical space occupied by 30 pixels on the iPad and 60 pixels on the retina is the same when measured with a ruler.

Comment: the "scale" is done by the OS for iPad and iPad Retina? When (which version) this technology is introduced?

Comment: The `scale` is decided by the device's hardware. It was introduced with the iPhone 4.